# Javascript PostBack doesn't work if in iframe under android

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net, html, xss

I developed Asp.NET website few months ago. I hosted it on some server and used free alias for website address. Alias uses iframe in which website content is shown. Example:
my site original address mysite.myhost.address.com, and alias address looks like this mysite.alias.com, and here is the code of an alias page that contains my original site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link rel="Shortcut icon" href="" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;" src="mysite.myhost.address.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" name=""></iframe>

<noframes>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      no frames
   </div>
</noframes>



</body>
</html>
```

The problem is with links generated from aspx page (they triggers postback using javascript) - on android devices any of such link does not work if page is displayed in iframe. If I go in android browser directly to my original web site address everything works fine. Is there any solution for this? Obviously I can't change any attributes of iframe page. I can change only my original website...

**Edit**

sample of javascript that doesn't work (this is normal javascript which is generated from asp:Link control) looks like this:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$NewsList$ctl00$lnkProgramTitle','')
```

link look like this:

```
<a id="MainContent_NewsList_ctl02_lnkMore" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39; ctl00$MainContent$NewsList$ctl02$lnkMore&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">More</a>
```

Comment: Sounds like you are hitting the XSS sandbox, can you post the javascript?  What other browsers have you tried? (chrome/safari?)

Comment: On every normal desktop browser it works fine. Problem is only under android. I've tested it on stock browser, dolphin and maxthon under android and on every browser such behaviour occurs.